# Vuetify SSR pagination

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to build pagination using vuetify pagination component and nuxt.js but it's not work with server side rendering.

I added nuxt.js link using code from https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4855. It's work on client side but on server side it return error "render function or template not defined in component: anonymous"

Anyone have idea how to build correct SSR pagination or how to fix my solution?

Comment: It's not sctual error. Restart your app and show first error message. And vuetify work fine on SSR

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this thread is still valid but this is my solution for  vuetify pagination with nuxt.

```js
 <script>
import PostList from "@/components/site/PostList";
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  components: {
    PostList
  },
  watchQuery: ["page"],
  async asyncData({ $axios, query }) {
    try {
      const page = query.page || 1;
      let { data } = await $axios.get("/articles/?page=" + page);
      return {
        posts: data.data,
        page: data.current_page,
        totalPages: data.last_page
      };
    } catch (e) {
      //  console.log(e); display errors
    }
  },
  methods: {
    next() {
      this.$router.push({ query: { page: this.page } });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
      <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="totalPages" @input="next"></v-pagination>
</template>
```